# Show a component after a certain date in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

What's the best way to render a component after a certain declared date in react native?

Not really sure on the best way to do so

Comment: I upvoted because im curious of this as well, the only thing i can think of is cron job ??? but not sure if this will be applicable in the context of react native.

Comment: @BARNOWL hmm interesting, another direction is maybe checking the current date with the declared one and see if its greater?? not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's still just JS (or TS), so you can just:

```
<View>
  {(new Date("2020-09-30")) > (new Date()) ? <Component /> : null}
</View>
```

Which would render `<Component />` if it's after `2020-09-30`, and `null` otherwise. That `new Date()` without any parameter returns current date and time.

Of course the `"2020-09-30"` value can be fetched from an API, a config file, or whatever suits your needs…

If you want to render the component even on the given day, not just after it, switch `>` for `>=` and set the right side of the expression to midnight:

```
(new Date("2020-10-12")) >= (new Date()).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) ? <Component /> : null
```

If you want to account for different timezones, it's a bit more tricky and perhaps using a library like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html) is an easiest option.

Comment: seems like a solution I had in my head! thanks will try it out and test out the performance of it :)

Comment: If you plan to re-render it often, it might be better to initialize the `Date` objects outside the render function and do just the comparison in it…(performance wise)

Comment: I'm planing to render a certain component after a declared date, and that's about it (so i guess performance is not going to be an issue) :) better solution instead of releasing a update for an app on the date

Answer (score 0):

You can store the certain declared date in async storage and check it inside the proper render function to show/hide the component.